Finding the least time path through n ordered points with bound acceleration
Let's assume we have a body in $2$-dimensional space, and we want it to pass through a series of points in a certain order with some given starting velocity, and a constraint that it can only move with a finite  acceleration, let's say smaller or equal to some number $A$.
I dont think a straight line would be the fastest path since the body would  have to stop at each point. How would one go about finding the fastest possible path given a series of points in $2$-dimensional space, starting velocity and the acceleration constraint

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your question starts out asking about 3d, but veers to 2D in the last sentence. Is that a typo?

Yeah it is a typo, thanks

This is generally done by optimizing a quantity called action (see more here) which is denoted $S$. It is given classically by the form:
$$S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathcal{L} dt$$
Here $\mathcal{L}$ is called the Lagrangian, and is simply $\mathcal{L} = T - V = \frac{1}{2} m (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) + \lambda \left( \ddot{x}^2 + \ddot{y}^2 - A^2 \right)$
where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier enforcing the acceleration limit you describe.
The Euler-Lagrange equations basically solve your problem, and are given by:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} \right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = 0,
$$
These lead to:
$$
m \ddot{x} = \lambda \ddot{x}, \quad m \ddot{y} = \lambda \ddot{y}.
$$
Thus, the accelerations must be proportional to the Lagrange multiplier $ \lambda$. To get the exact solution you solve the above equation, however, due to it often being quite complicated you can use numerical methods. The solution is a path that fits your criteria.
If you're interested, and want a bit of history as well as a gentle introduction to this concept, I highly suggest you watch this video on action.

Edit: I forgot to mention specifically that the total action through the $n$-ordered points is equal to the sum of the action over the partition of those points.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
